# Emulate green-screen monochrome monitor on DOSbox / D-Fend Reloaded

Tags: emulation, monitor, dosbox

I'm using DOSbox to play really old games I had on my PC XT with a green monochrome monitor. D-Fend Reloaded is set to run these games on CGA mode, it has colors, is there a way to make it more similar to the experience of a green-on-black monochrome screen of an old computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is to set the emulated graphics card to Hercules, and in-game use <kbd>F11</kbd> to toggle between the color schemes.

If you're using DOSBox, you'd want to change the machine entry in your [dosbox.conf](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf#.5Bdosbox.5D) file.

For D-Fend Reloaded, you'll want to:

- Right click on the game in question and choose Edit...
- Find "Graphics" in the left hand tree and click it
- Switch the "Video card" dropdown to "Hercules"
- Click the "Ok" button to save the changes

You can then launch the game and enjoy the monochrome graphics.

**NOTE:** In order for it to work, the game needs to provide support for Hercules video cards.

Comment: I have tested this in one single game, and apparently it doesn't support Hercules graphics. I will try in other games and see what happens.

Comment: @ruda.almeida, yes, this sort of thing is going to depend on the program, to an extent.  I believe that certain games also have different versions (ie, a version that only contained the color graphics, or only the monochrome, etc) so this won't work for every program.  It's the only way I know to get the "green and black" effect you're describing, though.

Comment: Well, it **does** work on games with Hercules support. Is there any way to cycle color on games with CGA/EGA/VGA support only?

Comment: @ruda.almeida, not really, no.  Past the Hercules days, the color palette was set by the game designers.  The best you can do is to find a version of the game with different graphics support, which can be challenging - there's less interest in the lower res/color versions of games than their more beautiful counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Set machine to cga_mono. In D-Fend Reloaded you will have to enter this manually.